# How to change one element while hovering over another use before not working

Tags: css, hover

**HTML**

```
<div class="related_files_data">
<h2>
    <a href="./?a=content.id&amp;id=96">example 1</a>
</h2>
<h2>
    <a href="./?a=content.id&amp;id=95">example 2</a>
</h2>
```

**CSS**

```
.related_files_data h2::before {
    color: #6dd7f8;
    content: "";
    font-family: fontawesome;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.related_files_data:hover + h2::before {
    color: #f8482e;
    content: "";
    font-family: fontawesome;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

I want to change the icons on the hover first element

With codes that do not work well writing

Comment: Which icon you want to change and on which hover ?

Comment: With codes that do not work well writing

Comment: If I understand correctly http://jsfiddle.net/j6w3e2ov/

Comment: @DmitryB. please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `selector:state:psuedo`, you can target a selector on its state:

```
.related_files_data h2:hover:before{
    color: #f8482e;
    content: "";
    font-family: fontawesome;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```css
.related_files_data h2::before {
    color: #6dd7f8;
    content: "";
    font-family: fontawesome;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.related_files_data h2:hover::before {
    color: #f8482e;
    content: "";
    font-family: fontawesome;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="related_files_data">
<h2>
    <a href="./?a=content.id&amp;id=96">example 1</a>
</h2>
<h2>
    <a href="./?a=content.id&amp;id=95">example 2</a>
</h2>
```